# Reactjs how to initialize array object in state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to reactjs and i'm learning to change state in reactjs. I'm trying to initialize an array object in state with unknown length, and later update the array object using set state. Following is the code:

```
state = {
  error: null,
  temperature: null,
  isLoaded: false,
  Weather5days: [],
};
```

So I have initialized Weather5days as an array, with unknown length. 
I get the data for Weather5days through API as json, so after fetch, I do this:

```
then(json => {
  var newArr = json.Forecasts.map(function(val) {
    //Forecasts have length of 5 array
    return {
      date: val.Date,
    };
  });

  console.log(newArr); // I checked, data is copied correctly in newArr.

  this.setState({
    Weather5days: newArr, //set state of the weather5days
  });
});
```

Now above code works with no error, but when I call console.log(this.state.Weather5days), the array is empty. So I thought the way of initializing Weather5days was wrong so I tried the following:

```
state = {
  error: null,
  temperature: null,
  isLoaded: false,
  Weather5days: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}], //array object of length 5
};
```

and It works. This is half the solution because in certain circumstances, you don't know the length of the array(that comes from the API) and I cannot afford to do literally do [{},{}..] everytime. What is the proper way of initializing array object with unknown length in state?

Comment: use the push method in array in order to put the value in the array, kinda like this. this.state.Weather5days.push(newArr);

Comment: @JohnWick if i directly push to Weather5days that would be directly mutating the state which should be avoided in reactjs as far as I know

Comment: You can update your state like this `this.setState({ Weather5days: [...this.state.Weather5days, newArr] })` or like this:  `this.setState({ Weather5days: this.state.Weather5days.concat([newArr]) })`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you set `array` in state you need to verify its updated state in `callback`. Because of the behavior of states in react are asynchronous.

```
 this.setState({
    Weather5days: newArr  //set state of the weather5days
  },()=> {
     console.log(this.state.Weather5days); 
  });
```

I think you are missing this point only.

Answer (score 2):

Hi your defined the Weather5days as empty array and adding the newArr to it but you should take the previous state of array and add your newArr to the state like this

```
this.setState({
Weather5days : [...this.state.Weather5days, newArr]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

```
const updated = this.state.Weather5days.slice(); 
updated.push(newArr); 
this.setState({Weather5days:updated});
```

Comment: no luck :( nothing at the moment works without initializing Weather5days:[{},{},{},{},{}] at the moment..keeps on returning empty array

Answer (score 1):

hope this could work.please check

```
const {Weather5days}=this.state
              this.setState({
          Weather5days: [...Weather5days,newArr]
      });
```

Comment: no luck :( nothing at the moment works without initializing Weather5days:[{},{},{},{},{}] at the moment..keeps on returning empty array